# Will an object hanging in the air acculumate static charge over time?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge

I remember hearing of a simple experiment about an isolated conductor hanging in the air. Due to the presence of charged ions in the atmosphere, this conductor would slowly accumulate static charge over time due to collisions of the air molecules at the surface of the conductor. Then someone touching the conductor would get a small electric shock. An extreme example of this would be how airplanes accumulate static charge during flight, which has to be dissipated using [static dischargers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_discharger). However, I am more interested in whether this experiment could be done in an ordinary setting

I can't find any name/resources for this "experiment". If this is a true effect, I am particularly interested in learning about *the rate of charge accumulation over time and factors that might affect this rate* (such as shape of the conductor or atmospheric conditions), or any potential modelling that has been done on this effect.

Comment: This Feynmann lecture on atmospheric electricity might be of interest https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html

Comment: I think you want to look up contact electrification. It's a surprisingly poorly understood phenomenon on a molecular scale. The charging also occurs with non-conductors e.g. at an air water interface.

Answer (score 1):

If wind is blowing over the object in question, and that object is insulated from ground, then it is indeed possible to charge it up- and if the object has capacitance, then the quantity of stored charge can reach lethal levels.

This occurred some years ago in the case of a portable rubber-tired trailer containing an extremely large capacitor bank. The trailer had a grounding rod which was to have been driven into the ground whenever the trailer was parked, but this was not done, and the wind charged the capacitor bank. When a worker tried to open the door to the trailer and enter it, he was instantly killed.

...or, in the words of our university's safety engineer, the victim *died exponentially*.